# IE7 creates empty text notes between floated elements

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, whitespace, textnode

I'm working on a pagination sort of thing, which is simply just a bunch of floated anchor-tags inside a div. Now, in IE7, it inserts empty text nodes here and there, seemingly at random, which breaks the layout.

**Result:**
[image: Example of how it looks on different pages. Note the empty text nodes.]

Example of how it looks on different pages. Note the empty text nodes. Neat, huh?

**CSS:**

```
 .nwsPaging {
   width:200px; /* Have also tried fluid size */
   height:30px;
   display:block; }

.nwsPaging a {    
   width:auto; /* Have also tried fixed size */
   margin:0 0 0 1px;
   padding:2px 8px;
   border:solid 1px #ccc;
   background:#eee;
   float:left;    
   line-height:20px;        
   display:block;
   zoom:1;
   vertical-align:top; /* Should not do any difference */ }

.nwsPaging a:hover, .nwsPaging .isActive {  
    background:#D150A1;
    color:#fff;
    display:block; /* Should be redundant, but just in case */
    zoom:1; }
```

As you can see, I've tried some different things, including setting a fixed width for the container and the floated -tags, plus giving it hasLayout. The .isActive class has nothing special in it, and it makes no difference if I never add the class.

I had the exact same problem in a different system, however I can't remember how I fixed it. I don't have access to the code, and the inspector is no help.

Bonus info:
The site is built on HTML5Boilerplate, which uses [normalize reset CSS](http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/).

**Edit:**
The markup is very simple, and although the tags are dynamically created, there should be no line breaks which could possibly create empty text nodes.

How the markup should be presented as parsed:

```
<div class="nwsPaging clearfix">
   <a href="foo">Previous</a>
   <a href="bar">1</a>
   <a href="bar" class="isActive">2</a>
   <a href="bar">3</a>
   <a href="baz">Next</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't find the article I read a while ago to check if I'm remembering right, but if you try display:block for the containing div then it shouldn't (i think) leave space for text nodes?

Comment: Can you make a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/) test case?

Comment: @Helen
I have tried making the parent a block element (though as a div, it should already be), as well as setting fixed and fluid widths, I've tried floating it, making clearfixes all over, setting the position etc.

Comment: Are you getting the problem with IE8/9 in IE7 mode, or in 'real' IE7?
I've copied the css and html, and it looks fine in both IE8 and IE9 while they're in IE7 mode (although I had to make the parent div width a bit bigger - I've set it to 300). I also get empty text nodes after *every* <a> tag showing up. Can you copy the exact output of the div/a markup so we can see if that might be a bit different?

Comment: Actually, it looks like the CMS inserts those little non-breaking spaces, so I guess the problem has been identified. Thanks for your effort, and sorry for wasting yout time. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could actually be caused by line-breaks in your code.

Strip them and see if it still does that.

Comment: I see where you are coming from, but that shouldn't be the problem in this case. The tags are dynamically created, and there should be no line breaks in the markup.

Comment: After revisiting this, it seems this may very well be the problem, however it is dynamically created in the CMS, so I have little control over it. Unfortunately, they are reluctant to fix this very minor bug. :/